# Count number of succeeding sections within the text

Tags: sectioning, counters, totcount

Writing about structure of the remainder of my article in the Introduction section, I want to dynamically get how many sections are left to the end of the manuscript.

So in case my article consists of **six** sections in total, I would need a command **\foo** once called within the body of the first section, renders to **"five"** and so on.

Comment: `\the\numexpr 6-\thesection\relax`

Comment: 6 is not known and varies. @StevenB.Segletes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following stores the value of the `section` counter *minus* 1 as a `\label` at the end of the document. It's then retrieved using a direct form of `\ref` and turned into a string using [`fmtcount`](//ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fmtcount,xfp}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \def\@currentlabel{\inteval{\value{section}-1}}%
  \label{foolabel}%
}
\newcommand{\foo}{%
  \ifcsname r@foolabel\endcsname
    \expandafter\numberstringnum\expandafter{\expandafter\@firstoftwo\r@foolabel}%
  \else
    0%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\sloppy
\section{Introduction}
There are \foo{} remaining sections.

\section{First section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Fourth section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Fifth section}\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Since it uses the `\label`-`\ref` system to extract the last sectional number, you need to compile twice with every change in the number of `\section`s (so the `\ref`erences can settle).

---

If you're dealing with unnumbered sections and want to include them as well (typically a reference section), then you can use the following setup:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fmtcount,xfp}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{totsection}

\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\stepcounter{totsection}\oldsection}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \def\@currentlabel{\inteval{\value{totsection}-1}}%
  \label{foolabel}%
}


\newcommand{\foo}{%
  \ifcsname r@foolabel\endcsname
    \expandafter\numberstringnum\expandafter{\expandafter\@firstoftwo\r@foolabel}%
  \else
    0%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\sloppy
\section{Introduction}
There are \foo{} remaining sections.

\section{First section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Fourth section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Fifth section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section*{Sixth section}\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

It uses a different counter `totsection` that counts a section whether it's numbered or not.

Comment: Doesn't work in my case. What if the document contains Appendices and/or References after the last \section?

Comment: @mhnrahmani: Shouldn't matter, unless they're called with `\section*` (an unnumbered section). You should provide a *complete* minimal example that shows the type of setup you have to deal with. Can you do that?

Comment: @mhnrahmani: I've added an update to my answer that counts numbered and unnumbered sections.

Comment: Well, the reason it doesn't work for me is that my template resets the section counter in order to categorize the appendices with A.B.C letters I guess. I am working on my own local repo. but heres the template I am working on: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/mdpi-article-template/fvjngfxymnbr

Comment: @mhnrahmani: What about my updated option that uses a new counter?

Comment: I don't want to include unnumbered sections. However since they exist, they don't let the foolabel return the correct value of the last numbered section.

Comment: @mhnrahmani: At this point I think it's best that you provide the community with a *complete*, *minimal* example of your setup and the expected output. Your current general question has been answered, even with adaptation. Can you do that? See [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Comment: The first part of your answer worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

EDITED to auto-calculate the number of sections in the document.

If you want the code to calculate the total number of sections, the `refcount` package can help.  One can use an `\AtEndDocument` hook to set the label to capture the final section number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcommand\sectionsleft{\the\numexpr 
  \getrefnumber{mylastsection}-\thesection\relax}
\AtEndDocument{\label{mylastsection}}
\begin{document}
\section{First}

My sections left are \sectionsleft.

\section{Second}

My sections left are \sectionsleft.

\section{Third}
\section{Fourth}
\section{Fifth}

My sections left are \sectionsleft.

\section{Last}

There are \sectionsleft{} sections remaining.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't there a way to retrieve sections count without manually labeling the last section like so? (Take into account what if an extra section with another label adds to the document later? Then the label used in \newcommand should update as well)

Comment: @mhnrahmani If you place the label immediately before the `\end{document}`, you should be covered.

Comment: @mhnrahmani Better still, you can place in the preamble the following: `\AtEndDocument{\label{mylastsection}}`.

Comment: @mhnrahmani You should also note that using a `\label`/`\ref` approach, two compilations are required to resolve any changes in the total number of sections.

Answer (score 1):

The package `totcount` does this with minimal intervention.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{totcount}

\regtotcounter{section}

\begin{document}

This paper consists of \total{section} sections.

\section{A}
\section{B}
\section{C}
\section{D}
\section{E}
\section{F}

\end{document}
```

[image]